# Disk Brake shudder felt through fork and frame

Tags: disc-brake

I have a muddy fox storm and when I use the front brake, it starts to shudder starting from the wheel and working up. It isn't that bad if I do it gently. Also, this is only a fist bike so I guess it doesn't matter if these things happen? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you ever replaced the pads and cleaned the rotor ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, assess your **headset**. A loose headset allows feeble vibrations to make the bike shudder. This  [tutorial](http://www.artscyclery.com/learningcenter/tightenyourheadset.html) over at Art's Cyclery will guide you through the process of taking care of it: all you'll need is a medium sized Allen Key.

If the headset looks just fine, it's time you get to your **break calliper** and **rotor**. I recommend that you sand your rotor and break pads a bit (until they look nice and smooth) with a medium grit sandpaper, wipe them down with some 90% v/v isopropyl alcohol nicely, reconfigure and bed them in. Also make sure that the calliper is **aligned** just right, if the calliper isn't approximately parallel to the rotor, it can make the thing happen. I would recommend using the *[business card method](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R0ltnBUCEdk)* to align the calliper. Doing this will almost certainly cure the bike of the issue. 
I hope this helps. :)

**--**

Edit: Also make sure that your pads have enough braking material on them before reconfiguring them.

Comment: Good answer. A link to the Park Tool tutorial and a description of the credit card method would make it even better. Also, a method I've heard of for aligning the caliper is to loosen the caliper slightly, spin the wheel while the bike is in a stand, then apply the brake and tighten the caliper while holding the brake on. Is that a widely accepted method? I guess the idea is it uses the rotor itself to align the caliper.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions: I've updated the answer with the links for the tutorials. I chose Art's Cyclery's tutorial cause I found out that Park Tool's went way beyond the tightening process. The method you talked of doesn't work as well if we don't keep something in between the inner pad and the rotor cause it makes the calliper align right but too close to the rotor, resulting in rubbing and sounds. The card ensures we've got just the right amount of space going in between the pad and the rotor. Cheerio. :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably a bit of dirt/contamination on either the Pads or rotor.
Might even be time to replace pads